# $X=2(A)−(A'∩ B)+3(A ∩ B ∩ C ')$ Compute $P(X\leq1)$.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have this probability question which was in one of archived exams of my course

> Let us take $C ⊂ A ∩ B$, $P(A)=P(B)=0.6$, $P(A∩B)=0.3$, $P(C)=0.2$ and let us consider the random variable $X=2(A)−(A'∩ B)+3(A ∩ B ∩ C ')$. Compute $P(X\leq 1)$ and $E(X)$.

I have tried to solve it as below, I just need to know if my approach for the solution is right:

$P(X) = 2P(A) − P(A'∩ B) + 3P(A ∩ B ∩ C ') $

$P(A'∩ B) = P(A) - P(A ∩ B)$

$P(A ∩ B ∩ C ') = P [(A ∩ B) ∩ C '] = P(C) - P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = 0$

because $C ⊂ A ∩ B$ then $P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(C)$

$P(X) = 2P(A) - [P(A) - P(A ∩ B)] + 3(0)$

$P(X) = 2P(A) - P(A) + P(A ∩ B) =  P(A) + P(A∩ B) = 0.6 + 0.3 = 0.9$

Comment: What is the meaning of e.g. $(A)$? Indicator of set $A$ maybe? What do you mean with $P(X)$?

Comment: (A) is indicator of set (A) and by P(X) i mean the Probability of (X)

Comment: Probability of $X$?? But $X$ is a **random variable**. It has a distribution (not a probability). Expressions like $P(X\leq1)$ and $\mathbb EX$ make sense, but $P(X)$ does not make sense.

Comment: How can I find the distribution of X  ? Any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** (for finding the distribution of $X$):

The sets $C$, $A\cap B\cap C^c$, $A\cap B^c$, $A^c\cap B$ and $A^c\cap B^c$ are disjoint and cover the whole space.

Based on the data in your question you can find the probabilities of these sets.

For each of these sets find out what value $X$ takes on it.

---

**edit:**

$A=C\cup(A\cap B\cap C^c)\cup(A\cap B^c$ so that $(A)=(C)+(A\cap B\cap C^c)+(A\cap B^c)$.

Consequently: $$X=2(C)+5(A\cap B\cap C^c)+2(A\cap B^c)-(A^c\cap B)$$

This reveals that $X$ takes values in $\{-1,0,2,5\}$ and it remains to find $P(X=i)$ for $i\in\{-1,0,2,5\}$.

For example: $$P(X=2)=P(C\cup(A\cap B^c))=P(C)+P(A\cap B^c)=0.2+0.3=0.5$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but after calculating the probability of the sets above , how for each of the sets will find the value of X , for example the probability of the set (A ∩ B') as i calculated is 0.3, how to figure out the value of X for that probability ?

Comment: I have added something to make things more clear.

Comment: For your last addition may I know how you obtained the values of i ?

Comment: if $x=2p+5q+2r-s$ where $p,q,r,s\in\{0,1\}$ and **at most one of them** takes value $1$ then $x\in\{-1,0,2,5\}$

Comment: Thanks for your reply and hint but still could not solve the problem, I can't relate the probability of the events with the idea of random variable.

Comment: If $X$ is a random variable then  $\{X=i\}$ is an event for every $i$. Finding out the probability of that event is the same as finding out $\Pr(X=i)$. See there the relation between probability of events and (the distribution of) random variable $X$. Do you understand my calculation of $\Pr(X=2)$?